# Fixing formula for checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, google-sheets-formula, filtering

There is a formula (highlighted in yellow in the table) that generates a table from the raw data into statistics for a particular team:

let(Σ,map('Data sheet'!A:A,'Data sheet'!B:B,'Data sheet'!C:C,'Data sheet'!D:D,'Data sheet'!E:E,'Data sheet'!F:F,'Data sheet'!G:G,
lambda(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,IF(a="",,{a,INDEX(IF(b=B1,{"H",c,d,e,f,g},IF(c=B1,{"A",b,e,d,g,f},)))}))),
filter(Σ,(INDEX(Σ,,2)<>"")))

I need to adapt this formula so, that the checkboxes above it help to further filter these stats by the criteria next to these checkboxes (tournament, opponent, home/away)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tE_OlT8VsLPWOsqDKPm548QC3hImKnQnF-Pq0oQrV1M/edit#gid=812840813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added formula to your sheet. Please do test it out.

```
=let(Σ,map('Data sheet'!A:A,'Data sheet'!B:B,'Data sheet'!C:C,'Data sheet'!D:D,'Data sheet'!E:E,'Data sheet'!F:F,'Data sheet'!G:G,'Data sheet'!H:H,                
          lambda(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,IF(a="",,{a,INDEX(IF(b=B1,{"H",c,d,e,f,g,h},IF(c=B1,{"A",b,e,d,g,f,h},)))}))),
          Δ,filter(Σ,(INDEX(Σ,,2)<>"")),
          query(Δ,"where Col2<>'' "&
               if(C4,"and Col8='"&B4&"'",)&
               ifs(E4*not(C4)," and Col8='"&D4&"'",E4*C4," or Col8='"&D4&"'",TRUE,)&
               if(C5,"and Col2='"&B5&"'",)&
               ifs(E5*not(C5)," and Col2='"&D5&"'",E5*C5," or Col2='"&D5&"'",TRUE,)&
               if(C3,"and Col3='"&B3&"'",)))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! But what if remove P column with tournament names and fix score display for Champions L matches? For EPL matches - ideal work, thank you